# How can I use BeforeDoubleClick to cycle through more than two colours?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that plots my personal targets down the left with the methods of completion along the top.
[image]

For each cell in the matrix, I want to double click to cycle between having an empty cell with red background, a green cell saying "Planned", and a green cell saying "Complete" with strikethrough.

I am able to use BeforeDoubleClick to toggle between the red cell and the "Complete" cell with strikethrough, but I can't cycle between all three using only double click.

The code I have:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Select Case Target.Value = "Complete"
    Case True: Target.Value = ""
        With Target.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Target.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        End With
        Target.Font.Italic = False
        Target.Font.Bold = False
        With Target.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
    Case Else: Target.Value = "Complete"
        With Target.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Target.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        End With
        Target.Font.Bold = False
        Target.Font.Bold = True
        Target.Font.Italic = True
        With Target.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = True
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
End Select
End Sub
```

I know I could use `BeforeLeftClick`, but I prefer to keep it all using the same shortcut.

Comment: If you're actually cycling, there should be an order and you can set-up your `Select` to dictate... I can give an example, though I feel that you'd be better off using Conditional Formatting based on what the value in the cell is... is "Complete" then strikethrough and make green the entire row, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice: Separate the tasks. Don't put too much logic into the trigger (the event routine) itself. In the following example, the event routine just checks if the target cells qualifies for the logic: You don't want to overwrite the content of the first columns or the header row. If okay, it calls a routine (`cycleStatus`) that does the work.

The routine itself first sets the value of the cell. It uses an If-ElseIf construct, but you can also use SelectCase, it's just a matter of taste.

After setting the content, the cell is formatted. You have a lot of unnecessary code, probably as a result of the macro recorder. I reduced it to the necessary commands to set the background color and the strike through, maybe you need to adapt it to set the color you want, change also the font color and so on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Ensure that you set only cells in the middle of your table.
    If Target.Row > 2 And Target.Column > 4 And Cells(Target.Row, 4) <> "" And Cells(2, Target.Column) <> "" Then
        cycleStatus Target
    End If
End Sub


Sub cycleStatus(cell As Range)

    ' --- Step 1: Set cell content
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "Planned"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "Planned" Then
        cell.Value = "Complete"
    Else
        cell.Value = ""
    End If
    ' The following lines would do the same:
    'Select Case cell.Value
    '    Case ""
    '        cell.Value = "Planned"
    '    Case "Planned"
    '        cell.Value = "Complete"
    '    Case Else
    '        cell.Value = ""
    'End Select
       
    ' --- Step 2: Format cell
    With cell.Interior
        .ThemeColor = IIf(cell.Value = "", xlThemeColorAccent2, xlThemeColorAccent6)
        .TintAndShade = 0.6
    End With
    
    With cell.Font
        .Strikethrough = (cell.Value = "Complete")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off with using if statements for this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
If Target.Value = "Complete" Then
    Target.Value = ""
    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Target.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    End With
    Target.Font.Italic = False
    Target.Font.Bold = False
    With Target.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
    Target.Value = "Planned"
    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Target.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    End With
    Target.Font.Bold = False
    Target.Font.Bold = True
    Target.Font.Italic = True
    With Target.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
ElseIf Target.Value = "Planned" Then
    Target.Value = "Complete"
    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Target.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    End With
    Target.Font.Bold = False
    Target.Font.Bold = True
    Target.Font.Italic = True
    With Target.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = True
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: `If` and `Select` are interchangeable in this regard.  You can present the same info inside of a `Case`, to change the `Target.Value`, etc.

Comment: Of course, but an if statement feels a lot less ambiguous for something as simple as this. If there were many more options then a select would probably be simpler. But, if you are going to use a select it should be by selecting the value rather than the boolean response to its value.

Comment: Amount of options has no inherent bearing on when to use one over the other, though `Select` is typically easier to assess multiple criteria in a more legible manner... as for the OP's use of `Select`, `Select Case Target.Value // Case "Complete"`, etc., would seem much more appropriate.  Seems there are a lot of things tucked inside of the Cases that are not really necessary.